# send hexstring to a serialport

Tags: php, serial-port

i am able to send data in terms of string  to a serial port by using

```
fwrite($this->_dHandle, $this->_buffer,1024);
```

it print string on the paper but my requirement is to print image in thermal printer i have the proper hex string to print image
in c# there is a option like

```
comport.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

data is in the form of byte array
when i convert the hex string to byte array and send it to the serial port it just print `Array`.Is there any overload function to send byte array to serial port in `PHP5.3`
Thnx in advance

Comment: thnx for reply where to use `join()`?

Answer (score 0):

No, php's fwrite doesn't have such a mechanism.  However, the function itself can be used with binary strings, so you just have to create a binary string, and probably the easiest way to do that is using the function [pack](http://php.net/pack).

Note: if your OS distinguishes between text and binary files (Windows does) the file should be opened as such (modeflag b, see [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)).

Comment: thnx FVU can you please tell how the string looks like

Comment: Check out the examples on the pack manual page I linked, they show the different ways and methods that can be used.  I'd guess that the "C" format specifier is what you want.  As pack doesn't accept arrays in its input I'm afraid you'll have to loop over the data.